# Setting up encryption on a SQL2012 Database - how to?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption

I am not really a DBA, but I have a requirement to set up NIST-approved Encryption on some databases.

Looking around online, there appears to be a few varieties of Encryption for SQL, but the terms are somewhat unfamiliar with me.

FIPS-140 algorithms are enforced via Group Policy on the hosting machine, but I suspect that's not what the desired outcome is.  I noticed that inside of SQL Management Studio that if I go into a given database's properties, there is at the bottom of the "Options" menu something that says "Encryption Enabled:  False".

Would setting just that one entry to "True" enable database encryption, or is there much more to it than that?  There does not appear to be any way to tell the system what kind of Encryption to use, so I remain skeptical.  If this is the case, what are the implications?  What would it even encrypt the data with, even?

Is this an instance where I need to deploy "TDE" - "Transparent Database Encryption"?  Is there another method I need to pursue?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to encrypt ? I believe that is the key question here. This will dictate which technology can be used.

Comment: Zapcon, the requirement is to encrypt specific databases (rather than, say, the entire machine - wherein I'd probably use BitLocker).  I'd thought I'd included that in the original post but I may not have been all that clear.  If there's a more specific detail I'd need to provide, I'm currently in the dark (as it says "data in each database").

Answer (score 0):

What kind of encryption you are looking for?

If you are looking for data encryption at rest or in backups you should focus on TDE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15

If you are looking for data encrypted in communications between clients and instance, you should go for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15